# What is Yahweh translated to in the arabic Bible?

Tags: hebrew, hebrew-bible

Is Yahweh translated as allah in the arabic Bible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a good source that discusses this at length.  See https://www.ijfm.org/PDFs_IJFM/23_4_PDFs/Thomas.pdf

In summary, "In Arabic translations it is transliterated as yahwah or translated as rabb (Lord), corresponding to the Jewish custom of using adonai in place of saying the divine name. Translations of YHWH in other languages used in the Islamic world have followed the precedent of the Arabic in either transliterating YHWH and/or using a word for Lord (rabb in Bambara and Somali, khodavand in Persian, Pashto, Sindhi, and Urdu, Tuhan in Indonesian). The exceptions to this practice are the Malay translations of 1912 and 1988 that use Allah for YHWH; the Biatah translation used in Sarawak, Malaysia, and the Tausug translation used in Jolo, Philippines, followed the precedent of the Malay translations."

Footnote 13 adds, "The completely revised Malay Bible of 1996, however, restored the practice of translating elohim as Allah. This was at the advice of the Malaysian church leaders, who considered the translations of 1912 and 1988 as not being exegetically accurate or faithful to the original texts. Thus the rendering of the divine names returned to the precedent established in the history of the Malay/Indonesian translations since 1629. The Biatah translation is also being revised to restore Allah as the translation of elohim. Information from Daud Soesilo, “Translating the Names of God Revisited: Field Experience from Indonesia and Malaysia,” (a paper presented at the Annual Meeting of the SBL/AAR in November 2000), pp. 4 and 8."